# Excel crashing on repeatedly opening and closing workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

In Excel2003 I'm seeing a strange thing happening with a macro I wrote to automatically modify a list of workbooks. I've got a list of 12000 workbooks to modify,so I need to open each one in turn, do stuff inside and then save and close.
After about 1000 workbooks have been processed (sometimes a few hundred more), Excel just crashes.

Here is pseudo-code for what I am doing

```
public sub ProcessWorkbooks()

    dim i as Integer
    dim targetWorkbook as Workbook

    With thisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("A15")
        Do While .Offset(i, 0).Value <> ""
            set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(.Offset(i, 3).Value)
            If targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
                Goto NextIteration
            End If
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Call ProcessWorkbook(targetWorkbook)
            Call targetWorkbook.Save
            DoEvents
            Call targetWorkbook.Close
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
NextIteration:
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

end sub
```

My first thought was a memory leak, but then I think Excel should become really slow before crashing, but the execution speed stays the same right up to the crash (I haven't sat there and looked at it for several thousand workbooks though...).
Is there something in Excel itself that can cause this kind of crash to happen? Maybe the history needs clearing out or something like that?
Has anybody had this happen before?

Comment: Is it tolerable to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and would it help?

Comment: I am actually using that already. I will amend the code I posted to show where. Do you think the position in the code where I am usnig it could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I believe `Application.ScreenUpdating` can (and maybe better) be placed outside `Do...Loop` or even `With`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing that at the time, but decided against it as I would like to see the application do something rather than appear to be frozen. I'm also wary of blanket use of ScreenUpdating = false, because if an error occurs you might be stuck with a frozen screen.

Comment: That's one thing I don't like `ScreenUpdating`, and that's why I ask "is it tolerable" at the beginning. But now you're "flickering" `ScreenUpdating` inside a loop, which I think maybe bad for a long time job. Would it help to remove this and use `DoEvents` in `ProcessWorkbook(wb)`?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: I would create a new worksheet within the master workbook and record times for each processed workbook.  This will help detect any patterns.  I would include `Set targetWorkbook = Nothing` after each close to ensure memory is released.  I agree that `Application.ScreenUpdating = False/True` per workbook is a bad idea; I use a simple form (xxx of 12,000 say) to give an indication of progress.

Comment: Add one line after you save and before you close the workbook. `Doevents`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added the DoEvents in my macro and removed the ScreenUpdating from inside the loop. Just to show how clueless I am, Apart from avoiding screen flicker, why is it a bad idea to have this in the loop?

Comment: can you show us the code where you added the `Doevents`?

Comment: I've added it in my code. I have it after the .Close call as you suggested. To be honest I always thought that DoEvents was for forms? I am basically getting a frozen screen now whilst I execute.

Comment: `DoEvents` asks the application to get ready for the torment, while `ScreenUpdating = False` asks the application to shut up while tormenting...

Comment: Well, I must be doing it wrong, because DoEvents is not giving me any joy at all. Thanks for all the comments, I guess the problem I have is due to something unknown and mysterious.

Comment: Have you thought about just adding some basic logging to a text file? This would be my starting point to try and identify exactly how far the code gets. Might be an issue with a particular workbook you are opening?

Comment: I am doing something similar in that I output status updates to the master workbook after each individual operation has been performed one one workbook (say, open, read, modification 1, 2, etc., close) and save the workbook regularly so I can follow progress. The workbooks on which the macro fails seem just fine as far as I can tell and they process fine once I resume the macro from the failure point.

Comment: @user643192: May I see your sample file? or if I can see the procedure `ProcessWorkbook(targetWorkbook)`? Also where are you setting the value of `i`?

Comment: Normally this is a bad idea but try creating a single separate `Excel.Application` object and use it to open/save/close the workbooks to be processed. When this crashes, it hopefully shouldn't affect the `Excel.Application` object which runs the `ProcessWorkbooks` macro. This might give you a better insight into what's going wrong or, more simply, a way to use error-handling to restart the process

Comment: Siddarth Rout, sorry, but I can't hand out the worksheet, because it is work related and contains some sensitive information. About i, I forgot to include it when I simplified the code. It is set inside the loop, typical i = i + 1. I'l add it now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried with newer Excel, say, 2010?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'd love to use Excel 2007 or 2010, but my company is really bad for upgrading their software and everybody is still on Excel 2003. Sigh.